# I'm setting a href mailto from jQuery, but I don't know how to set the target _blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hyperlink in my webpage :

```
<a id="contact" href="#">contact</a>
```

And then in jQuery I have :

```
$("#contact").click(function() {
    document.location.href = "mailto:info@mail.com";
});
```

When user clicks the link, it opens in the same window, how can I open mail in the other window ? I tried adding `target="_blank"` to the `<a..` but then the contact form opened in the same window and my webpage opened in another window... How can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you look into window.open?

Comment: What is the reason for using JavaScript rather than adding it to the HTML?

Comment: `window.open("mailto:info@mail.com", "_blank");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `window.open` instead of `document.location.href`

```
  $("#contact").click(function() {
    win = window.open('mailto:info@mail.com', '_blank');
    if (win) {
        //Browser has allowed it to be opened
        win.focus();
    } else {
        //Browser has blocked it
        alert('Please allow popups for this website');
    }
});
```

Comment: hm what exactly here is `'window name', 'window settings'`? should I substitute it with some other values?

Comment: Actually, only the first parameter is needed for what you want. I edited my answer

You can find the full documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.open like this :

```
  var win = window.open(mailto:info@mail.com, '_blank');
  win.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be an alternative solution, where you wouldn't have to use jquery to detect the click, and avoid potential click/touch triggering twice.

```
$("#contact").attr("href", "mailto:info@mail.com").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Also, this shouldn't be blocked by popup blockers (as far as I'm aware).